# How to check which type of subscript operator is called, lvalue or rvalue?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdvector

I wrote a Vector wrapper class. And I want to overload the subscript operator for this class.

If a user want to set a value to an index which is bigger than the size. I will resize the vector size to index*2.

But if a user want to get a value from an index which is bigger than the size. I will throw an exception.

So, How can check these two situations in the overloaded operator method ?

Vector.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector {
  vector<T> v;
  public:
    T& operator[] (const int index);
    T getmax ();
    int add (T val);
    int size();
    int capacity();
};
```

Vector.cpp

```
#include "Vector.h"


template <class T>
T Vector<T>::getmax (){
  T retval;
  return retval;
}


template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[] (const int index){
    //How to check that which is called =>  v[5]=10(setting) or cout<<v[5]/getting)?
    if(index>v.size()-1){  
        v.resize(index*2); 
        return v[index];
    }
    else{
        return v[index];
    }
}


template <class T>
int Vector<T>::add (T val){ //return index
    v.push_back(val);
}


template <class T>
int Vector<T>::size (){
    return v.size();
}

template <class T>
int Vector<T>::capacity (){
    return v.capacity();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Vector.cpp"
#include <iostream>


int main () {
  Vector<int> myobject;

  myobject.add(67);
  myobject[2]=99;

  cout <<"myobject[0]:"<<myobject[0]<<endl;
  cout <<"myobject[1]:"<<myobject[1]<<endl;
  cout <<"myobject[2]:"<<myobject[2]<<endl;
  cout <<"myobject[3]:"<<myobject[3]<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't. The operator doesn't know about the expression it is called in.

Comment: This is simply bad design. You can work around some problems with it, but don't.

Answer (score 3):

You can overload `operator []` for `const` and non-`const` objects.

```
T& operator[] (const int index);
T const& operator[] (const int index) const;
```

However, if you have a non-`const` object, the first overload will be called even if your intention is to **get** and not **set**. If you want to implement different behavior between **get** and **set**, it will be better to have two such functions.

```
T const& get(int index) const;
void set(int index, T const&);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for `operator[]` to know whether the user intends to get or set. However, there is a workaround. You can make your `operator[]` return some type, let's call it `VectorSubscriptResult<T>`, that holds a reference to the vector and to the index that was requested. This type `VectorSubscriptResult<T>` would have an `operator T&`, which would be invoked if someone wanted to get the value, and an `operator=`, which would be invoked if someone wanted to set it. (I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader how to handle the case of `operator[]() const`.)

Comment: However this is how `vector<bool>` works and I think pretty much everybody is in agreement that it is bad

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think most of the badness comes from the fact that vector<bool> works differently from vector<T> with T != bool. It's not obvious to me that it would otherwise be that bad.

Comment: Perhaps but by extension people do expect `operator[]` in general to work a certain way too

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there is nothing wrong with having `operator[]` return a proxy object. The only other thing you might need to add to it is `operator&` if you want to take the address of an indexed element